# Installing qdap package in R

Tags: r, installation, qdap

I have been trying to install qdap in R (note I am using R version 3.3.1). I have been trying a couple of times and the installation freezes all the time. Do you know if there is anything i can do? I want to use the qdap package for some spell checking like it listed here: https://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2014/09/04/spell-checker-for-r-qdapcheck_spelling/
Thanks

Comment: Was is just frozen or any error? Perhaps changing the CRAN mirror?

Comment: I am the author of the qdap package.  I'd love to help if you give us more info about the error (please provide it).  That being said I really would encourage you to check out an excellent spelling package from Jeroen Ooms called hunspell: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hunspell/index.html

Comment: I also tried to install dap and this is the error message> library("qdap")
JavaVM: requested Java version ((null)) not available. Using Java at "" instead.
JavaVM: Failed to load JVM: /bundle/Libraries/libserver.dylib
JavaVM FATAL: Failed to load the jvm library.
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'openNLPdata', details:
  call: .jinit()
  error: JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs returned -1

Errore: package or namespace load failed for ‘qdap’